# React Not Loading Image when running code

Tags: reactjs, image

If someone can let me know if I'm using an improper format in order to load an image on react that would be amazing! I'm not an expert and any advice is greatly appreciated -- thank you in advance. The image that populates when I run the code just shows a broken img icon and when I try to run through the terminal it says that the image is called but not loaded.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Logo from "/Users/mauromartineziii/aqua-financial/src/logo.png";
import "./App.css";
import Photo from "/Users/mauromartineziii/aqua-financial/src/pexels-photo-3560168.jpeg";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section>
          <header>
            <img
              src="/Users/mauromartineziii/aqua-financial/src/logo.png"
              width="333"
              alt="Aqua Financial"
            />
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li>Financial Services</li>
                <li>Liquid Capital Asset</li>
                <li>Retirement</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </header>
        </section>

        <section id="main">
          <img src="Photo"></img>
          <div className="main-text">
            <span>Learn What An LCA™ Can </span> <br /> Do For You <br />
          </div>
          <div className="right-text">
            <span>Innovation Driven Banking</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            {" "}
            <button>Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

section {
  margin: 0 120px;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

header div {
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

#main {
  margin: 0 120px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

#main .main-text {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

`

Comment: Broken image indicates that your image is not available at the provided src location. Try using relative paths instead of absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to place the images you use in your project in the project directory and import them with a relative path, e.g:

```js
import Logo from "./logo.png";
```

You also want to use the the resulting variables for your `img` tags.

```js
<img
  src={Logo}
  width="333"
  alt="Aqua Financial"
/>
// ...
<img src={Photo} />
```